# Não consigo escrever em JTextArea

Tags: java, string

tenho a classe:

```
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class Semantico {

private String tipo;
private String variavel;


public void verificaSem(String stipo, String svariavel, JTextArea txtSemantico){

    this.tipo = stipo;
    this.variavel = svariavel;

    String tipo2 = "int";

    if (tipo==tipo2){

        txtSemantico.setText(tipo);
    }


}




}
```

Esse txtSemantico está na minha classe principal, e gostaria de escrever o conteudo da variavel tipo que é "int" se ela for igual ao conteudo do tipo2 que também é "int". A questão é que ele não escreve. Detalhe, se eu tirar a condição If e deixar o que está dentro do If, ele funciona. Obrigado.

Comment: Provavelmente os valores não são iguais, por isso não escreve, é um problema de lógica, no caso. Depure o código e veja se realmente está chegando igual. Dica: use `equals` pra comparar strings e não `==`

Answer (score 0):

Simples, é um erro semântico, quando se quer comparar duas `String` não se usa o operador de igualdade `==`, e sim `.equals()`, lembrando que `String` é um objeto, não uma variável do tipo primitivo !

> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html

Comment: Funcionar funciona, só não é recomendado. Isso não é bem um erro de lógica, e sim, semântico.

Comment: @diegofm Qual seria a forma recomendada de comparar duas `String` ?

Comment: Usando `equals`, eu me referi a usar o sinal `==` pra comparar strings. Pode funcionar em muitos casos, mas o equals é que foi feito pra isso.